# How to loop through in a wrapper class and print data in an another class

Tags: apex, integration, wrapper-class

Wrapper class:

```
public class Check_Request_Response_WS {

    public root root{get;set;}
    
    public class root{
        public list<ACC_DOCUMENT03> ACC_DOCUMENT03{get;set;}
        public String TransactionId{get;set;}
    }
    public class IDocControlRecordForInterfaceToExternalSystem{
        public String PartnerTypeOfReceiver{get;set;}
        public String PartnerTypeOfSender{get;set;}
        public String SenderPortSAPSystemExternalSubsystem{get;set;}
        public String PartnerNumberOfSender{get;set;}
        public String EDIMessageType{get;set;}
        public String ReceiverPort{get;set;}
        public String MessageType{get;set;}
        public String PartnerNumberOfReceiver{get;set;}
        public String NameOfBasicType{get;set;}
        public String CreatedOn{get;set;}
        public String OutputMode{get;set;}
        public String CreatedAt{get;set;}
        public String Direction{get;set;}
        public String IDocNumber{get;set;}
        public String SAPReleaseForIDoc{get;set;}
        public String Client{get;set;}
        public String StatusOfIDoc{get;set;}
        public String NameOfTableStructure{get;set;}
    }
    public class IDOC{
        public IDocControlRecordForInterfaceToExternalSystem IDocControlRecordForInterfaceToExternalSystem{get;set;}
        
        public list<GLAccountItem> GLAccountItem{get;set;}
        public list<CurrencyItems> CurrencyItems{get;set;}
        public Header Header{get;set;}
    }
    public class Header{
        public String DocumentType{get;set;}
        public String DocumentDateInDocument{get;set;}
        public String ReferenceDocumentNumber{get;set;}
        public String CompanyCode{get;set;}
    }
    public class GLAccountItem{
        
        public String SalesTaxCode{get;set;}
        public String CostCenter{get;set;}
        public String AssignmentNumber{get;set;}
        public String ItemText{get;set;}
        public String BusinessPartnerReferenceKey{get;set;}
        public String GeneralLedgerAccount{get;set;}
    }
    public class CurrencyItems{
        public String CurrencyKey{get;set;}
        public String AmountInDocumentCurrency{get;set;}
    }
    public class ACC_DOCUMENT03{
        public IDOC IDOC{get;set;}
    }
}
```

//--------------------------------------------->> In another class

```
Check_Request_Response_WS response = new Check_Request_Response_WS();

response = (Check_Request_Response_WS)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),Check_Request_Response_WS.class);

system.debug(' response :'+response); //I am getting response here.
```

**Now I want to loop through the wrapper and print each element of idoc.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your class and considering the JSON comes as

```
{
  "root" : {
    "TransactionId" : null,
    "ACC_DOCUMENT03" : [ {
      "IDOC" : {
        "IDocControlRecordForInterfaceToExternalSystem" : null,
        "Header" : null,
        "GLAccountItem" : null,
        "CurrencyItems" : null
      }
    }, {
      "IDOC" : {
        "IDocControlRecordForInterfaceToExternalSystem" : null,
        "Header" : null,
        "GLAccountItem" : null,
        "CurrencyItems" : null
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

---

You can do your null checks and isEmpty checks and do something like below to access `IDOC` like below.

```
response = (Check_Request_Response_WS)JSON.deserialize('{"root":{"TransactionId":null,"ACC_DOCUMENT03":[{"IDOC":{"IDocControlRecordForInterfaceToExternalSystem":null,"Header":null,"GLAccountItem":null,"CurrencyItems":null}},{"IDOC":{"IDocControlRecordForInterfaceToExternalSystem":null,"Header":null,"GLAccountItem":null,"CurrencyItems":null}}]}}',Check_Request_Response_WS.class);
if (response != null && response.root != null && response.root.ACC_DOCUMENT03 != null && !response.root.ACC_DOCUMENT03.isEmpty()) {
    for (Check_Request_Response_WS.ACC_DOCUMENT03 accDocument03 : response.root.ACC_DOCUMENT03) {
        System.debug(accDocument03.IDOC);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the class you're in, you have to specify the outer class name as well:

```
Check_Request_Response_WS response = (Check_Request_Response_WS)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),Check_Request_Response_WS.class);
for(Check_Request_Response_WS.ACC_DOCUMENT03 document03: response.root) {
    Check_Request_Response_WS.IDOC idoc = document03.idoc;
    // etc
 }
```

Unfortunately, your code is going to be very verbose, because we can't dynamically access properties of an object dynamically like we would in other languages. Your code is going to be longer than the actual wrapper itself.

You'll probably want to just `JSON.serializePretty` if you're just interested in seeing what it looks like.